# Is there a way to move a Trello Checklist to a different Card?

Tags: trello, trello-cards

I often need to consolidate (combine) Checklists from a couple of Cards into one Card.

Any way to do this?

Answer (score 9):

Just figured it out by accident:

If you create a new checklist, one of the options is to *Copy items from ...* [another checklist]